# why classification results using SVM is not good in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have some problem with svm. I used svmtrain and svmclassify for classification mass and no mass. I have data training 40 false positive and 13 true positive. when I test it (data testing that i used = data training) is working and gives accrurately 100%. but when I test it (data testing i take out from data training) data training (TP=8 FP=30) and data testing(TP=5 FP=10) . the result gives all the the data false positive. do have any idea about this problem? or it because the small number of data testing and training?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite normal that the independent test set could perform poorly, which means your model clearly tends overfit since you got 100% when fits training data. try adjust svm model parameter, apply data-preprocessing, especially standardization to decrease your fit in training and (hopefully) your independent test data. when two accuracy comes close, the model will be valid.

Comment: Ok . i want to make sure that 1. my classification is already right(because gives 100% when training data used for testing)? 2. should i used balanced the number of training data and testing data? (is it also the problem?). 3. what do u mean adjust model parameter?( do u mean I have to try another kernel and set the parameter? or there's another parameter? 4. if I used libsvm, is it will give better result? sorry for many question because I am beginner in this field. thank you

Comment: If you are using the libsvm package, you could look at the starter's guide. http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf that will be a lot of help. especially pay attention to the "grid search" technique.  100% with training data did not mean anything except possibility of overfitting. The thing important is the % correction on independent test data, and cross-validation data. I am not sure balancing will be a problem since it is highly problem-specific.